# Stage response to touch

Tags: android, libgdx, stage, scene2d

I want actors in a stage to respond to touch after specific time from the previous touch

e.g. I have an actor that responds to touch
by doing some stuff and I want non of the other actors to respond to touch until 1 second has passed

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work, rough pseudocode and real code mixed together - more for illustration.

```
... previous touch actions finished
stage.getRoot().setTouchable(Touchable.disabled);
Timer.schedule(new Task(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    stage.getRoot().setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
                }
               }
               , 1.0f        //    (delay in seconds)
              );
```